# Tree branching factor and depth

Tags: calculus, graph-theory

I have a  unresolved math problem about non-weighted trees.
Suppose we have a tree with branching factor $b$ and depth of most superficial solution as $d$.

From math i know that, if i use a **Breadth first algorithm**, in every iteration the number of generated nodes is $O(b^{d})$. **This is clear to me.**

But then i read that if i want an $O$ about the sum of **all** generated nodes, this is simply $O(b^{d+1})$.But i dont understand why and i wasnt able to *prove* this result. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in your setting visiting a node generates its children (and pushes them onto the BFS queue).

If your solution is at level $d$, then you will never visit a node at level $d+1$, but may potentially generate them all (as children of visited $d$-level nodes) except for the solution-node (which is a solution, so you don't generate children for it). So, if each of $b^{d}$ visited $d$-level nodes generates $b$ children, then you will have $b \cdot b^{d} = b^{d+1}$ of $(d+1)$-level nodes in total.

Furthermore, if $b \geq 2$, we have
$$b^0 + b^1 + \ldots + b^d \leq b^{d+1},$$
which gives us the bound for the sum of all nodes:
$$b^0 + b^1 + \ldots + b^d + b^{d+1} \leq 2b^{d+1}$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks so much. Which theorem states that $b^{0}+...+b^{d}\leq b^{d+1}$ ?

Comment: @Qwerto Just use induction: $$b^0 + \ldots + b^d \overset{\text{group}}{=} (b^0 + \ldots + b^{d-1}) + b^{d} \overset{\text{induction}}{\leq} b^d + b^d \overset{b \geq 2}{\leq} b \cdot b^d = b^{d+1}$$